# Python source code collection

Tags: python

Does anyone know anywhere there's a wide collection of Python source code on the net with decent documentation? If so, can someone post it up here?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Perhaps the [Python Standard Library](http://docs.python.org/library/)? Or are you looking for something more specific?

Answer (score 7):

I am not sure what you meant by "source code"? Source code of Python libraries or code examples and recipes?

Well the link to Python STL is great (@zenazn).

In addition to that if you are looking for specific issues and their solutions and recipes, I will suggest:

1. http://code.activestate.com/recipes/langs/python/
2. Stack overflow itself.

Though you won't find much documentation at these sources, but that is supplemented by great answers, comments and discussions.

Answer (score 6):

you can find a huge number of python libraries at the [cheese shop](http://pypi.python.org/pypi).

Answer (score 4):

A great place covering several libraries with very clear examples is:

http://nullege.com/codes/

Answer (score 3):

I like:

- [The Python Cookbook](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/langs/python/)
- [Google Code Search](http://www.google.com/codesearch)

Comment: FWIW, Google Code Search has since been shut down.

Answer (score 2):

The cpython source code (the original python project) is at http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/default/

Answer (score 0):

Not the Python itself but the 3rd party package source codes that you can even search within the source codes:

http://pydoc.net/